# COUNTIF with more than 3 criteria or use different formula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to get a count based on a specific entry in one column AND add the choice made from a separate column in my google sheets.
Should I use a different formula than COUNTIF since I have multiple entries to count?

Example:
Countif(I:I, "j", "k", "l") + Countif(J:J, "SPH", K:K "SPH")

Is there a better way to count more than 3 criterion in a column?  if so, could a second count be added to include a separate columns criterion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using [COUNTIFS](https://sheetsinfo.com/countifs-function-in-google-sheets/)

> **COUNTIFS** Function helps us get conditional counts within a range based upon multiple criteria’s. It’s a enhanced version of it’s [sic] sister function COUNTIF which also gives us conditional counts but only with a single criteria.

```
= COUNTIFS(criteria_range1, criterion1, [criteria_range2, criterion2, ...])
```

applied to your criteria:

```
= COUNTIFS(I:I, "j", I:I, "k", I:I, "l", J:J, "SPH", K:K, "SPH")
```